# Задача на Паскаль

Tags: pascal

Есть код прорисовки прямоугольника.

```
uses crt;
var i:integer;
begin
    TextSize(16);
    TextBold;
    textcolor (4);
    for i:=1 to 25 do begin
        gotoxy(27+i,1);
        write('*');
        gotoxy(27+i,23);
        write('*');
        gotoxy(27,i);
        write('*');
        gotoxy(52,i);
        write('*');
    end;
end.
```

Нужно аналогично нарисовать равнобедренный треугольник.

Comment: Почитайте [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help)

Comment: Рассчитайте смещения ребер треугольника для каждой горизонтали. Простейший случае  -  ребра под 45 градусов

Comment: Спасибо за оперативный ответ! Но, дело в том, что я не программист, от слова "совсем")) Это задание ребенку по информатике, а что и как сделать - увы, не знаю(

Comment: Ну так логику включите с ребёнком вместе. На i-й строчке первая звездочка будет на позиции n-i, вторая на позиции n+i, где n - общее количество строк

Comment: С логикой проблем нет. Есть проблемы со знаниями программирования в целом, и в языке Паскаль, в частности((( Я не знаю, что такое i. Не понимаю ( как и ребенок), как эту логику реализовать в коде. Это "китайский язык" для меня. А ребенок настаивает, что такое еще не проходили, они раньше просто алгоритмы придумывали))) Дистанционка(((( Извините..

Comment: Смотрите, вот здесь **for i:=1 to 25 do** Вам сказано, что **i** будет изменяться от 1 до 25. Для каждого значения будут выполняться действия от строчки **for** до первого **end**. Строка вида **gotoxy(x,y)** перемешает указатель в точку с координатами **x,y**, а следующая строка рисует там звездочку. Попробуйте с ребенком вместе прорисовать это на бумаге, проходя программу построчно. А потом так же прорисуйте треугольник. Станет понятнее, что здесь делается, и как ребенку ее поправить :)

Comment: Благодарю Вас, буду разбираться.

Answer (score 0):

Примерно так - на каждом шаге рисуется звёздочка слева от центральной линии и справа, и заполняется часть нижней стороны.

```
gotoxy(25,1); {вершина}
write('*');
for i:=2 to 25 do begin
    gotoxy(25-i+1,i);
    write('*');
    gotoxy(25+i-1,i);
    write('*');
    gotoxy(i,25);  {нижняя горизонталь}
    write('*');
    gotoxy(51-i,25);
    write('*');
end;
```

Comment: Большое спасибо!